# Creating a C# List collection equivalent VBscript two dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, collections, vbscript

VBscript:

```
arytwoDim(1,intLastBucketBlockIndex) =  "08:30 AM" 'TIME
arytwoDim(2,intLastBucketBlockIndex) =  5 'Resource QTY
```

I would like to create a List collection equivalent to vb array, so that I can mirror the logic with hard coded row,cols.

```
I tried loading list like this:
List<List<String>> arytwoDim = new List<List<String>>(); //Creates new nested List
arytwoDim .Add(new List<String>()); //Adds new sub List
arytwoDim [1][intLastBucketBlockIndex] = "08:30 AM"; //TIME
arytwoDim [2][intLastBucketBlockIndex] = 5;  //Resource QTY
```

I received this error: **'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'**

I confirmed that value intLastBucketBlockIndex contains is 0.

Please advise, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think your question is about C#, not VBScript. The example you show uses what is called a jagged array. This link may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed to solve problem.